# Where are Java JDK Sources?

Tags: java

I installed Java JDK but where can I find the sources? For one my homework, I'm asked to refer to one of the files ...

> check the source code of java.util.LinkedList. The Java source code of
>   this class can be found in the jdk package

Comment: see [Is it possible to browse the source of OpenJDK online?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/410756/309483)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, about `java.util.LinkedList` source: you can view it [here](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/LinkedList.java.htm) or [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/LinkedList.java.html), for example.

Then, aren't you looking for [openjdk-7-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/openjdk-7-source) or [sun-java6-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sun-java6-source) packages?

If not (may you prefer a Mercurial checkout or a tarball way or just want the most up-to-date sources), maybe this is what are you looking for?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use google and typed: "java jdk download"

then find this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

from there I find this

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-plugin-install.html

ok. hope You find this usefull.

Comment: And more find this: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct link for the LinkedList sources in mercurial repository for OpenJDK 8: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java